# Making a Windows USB Boot Drive on Mac, can you select a partition Style?

Tags: windows, boot, mac, rufus

I need to install Windows using my USB Stick. In Rufus, different partition types (UEFI with MBR, GPT etc.) are selectable. The problem is, I have only a Macbook and none of the soft, that I used, which were Boot Camp Assistant, Etcher, Unetbootin, had this feature.

I want to select a specific partition, because I don't want to erase valuable files on my Windows PC. Do I have an option to select it somehow on Mac?

Comment: my Windows PC.    ........   Use this for make the USB Key.

Comment: I have only my Mac available

Comment: Why do you need a Windows USB?  OR, go where this Windows PC is, and make the USB Key there. Otherwise your post is very unclear.

Comment: If it were so easy to "go somewhere", I would've. My question is: "Is there a way to make a Windows installation USB Drive for a particular partition style using a Macbook?" I think, it's a pretty straightforward question.

Comment: If you are trying to install Windows on a Mac, consider a Virtual Machine. Much easier and you can point to the download on your Mac in the VM App.

Comment: I have two separate PCs, one is a Mac, using which I want to create a Windows installation USB to install Windows onto other PC, which now has no OS (I referred to it as to a "Windows PC").

Comment: You can download the Windows ISO from the Microsoft Media Creation link onto a bootable USB.  Partitions not needed.  Boot from the bootable USB key on the "other PC" and install Windows. That will make the required partitions. I have done this.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/355930/85275

Comment: Sorry A…. I thought a Mac could do this.  Do you have a friend with a Windows machine who could assist you?